# Entity Framework: how to return a base type from L2E

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

Considering the following architecture:

- a base object 'Entity'
- a derived object 'Entry:Base'
- and a further derived object 'CancelledEntry:Entry'

In EntitySQL I can write the following:

```
[...] where it is of (only MyEntities.Entry) [...]
```

to return only objects of type Entry and no Entity or CancelledEntry.

In linq to sql, the following command will return objects of type Entry and CancelledEntry.

```
EntityContext.EntitySet.OfType<Entry>()
```

What is the syntax/function to use to return only objects of type Entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you apply an extension method on IQueryable< Entry > called ApplyBaseEntryFilter() which would apply this filter and return an IQueryable< Entry >.

This is an example of how to reuse linq query fragments. Using extension methods on IQueryable< Entity > is a great way to re-use queries as you should neve rneed to copy and paste query fragments around your application, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found a partial solution:

```
EntityContext.EntitySet.OfType<Entry>().Where( obj => !(obj is CancelledEntry) )
```

This is quite awful however, since if I create a new derived object, I have to go in all the queries and specifically add a condition to remove it.

There has to be a better solution